# Use Office 2000 proofing tools in Access 2010 Runtime

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office, spell-checking, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010 Runtime to run my custom database application. Office 2000 professional is also installed on the same machine. I use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling` a couple different place to perform a spell check on the data entered.

This works great on the full version of Access 2000 but when I open it up in 2010 Runtime I get the message `MS Access can't start the spell checker because it isnt' installed`. I know  if the full version of Office isn't installed the spell checking won't work.

Now for my question. The full version of Office is installed, but it is a different version. Is there any way to make Access 2010 Runtime use the Office 2000 proofing tools?

I really want to use 2010 runtime because of several UI improvements that my application uses. I know that I could go back to Access 2000 but that would be a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A late answer but it is still current...

Actually you can install the spellcheck and proofing tools via Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010.

- Download **Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010** from Microsoft and open it
- Choose **Customize**
- Click the **Microsoft Sharepoint Designer** icon and choose **Not available**
- Expand **Office Shared Features** and then **Proofing Tools**
- Customize the tools by expanding the languages ensuring **Spelling and Grammar checkers** is selected
- Install

Comment: This is *THE* answer in my opinion @JBES.  Although I am using the 2013 Runtime, I adapted your solution by downloading MS SharePoint Designer 2013 and then ensuring that Spelling and Grammar checkers were selected when I installed it.  When the install completed and I ran my runtime .accdr database, the spell check worked perfectly!  I'd been trying to solve that problem for a long time and your solution finally got it sorted.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a third party spell checker? Can you insert a custom WinForms controls developed in C# into an access database? What about a VB6 control? If you could find a control with spell checking using a third party library, that might work.

Comment: This: http://www.pcesoft.com/Access-Spell-Checker-Tool-Source-Code.html is what I came up with and it seems like it may work for me. The biggest drawback is the performance...

Answer (score 0):

## Using Excel's VBA Functions in MS Access:

You can call Excel functions from Access by adding a reference to Excel.

In the Access VBA Project, go `Tools` → `References`, and then locate and include the library **"`Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library`"** (or the newest version you have).

Then create an object referring to an Excel Application and call whatever commands as required.

For example, to check the spelling of a word or phrase:

```
Sub demo_Spellcheck()
   Dim textToCheck As String, excel As New excel.Application 'create Excel object
   textToCheck = InputBox("Enter a word or phrase:", "Spellcheck", "blah blah")

   If excel.Application.CheckSpelling(textToCheck) Then 'check spelling
       MsgBox textToCheck & vbLf & "is spelled Correctly", 64 'TRUE = correct
   Else
       MsgBox textToCheck & vbLf & "is mis-spelled", 16 'FALSE = misspelled
   End If

   Set excel = Nothing 'always cleanup after your objects
 End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- Office Docs : [**`Application.CheckSpelling` method** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.checkspelling)
- Office Docs : [**`Application.WorksheetFunction` property** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.worksheetfunction)